# Making diagrams smaller in beamer

Tags: beamer, diagrams

I want to shrink a diagram so that it fits on the page in a beamer document.  Here is what I have

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amscd,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[pdftex]{pict2e}
\usepackage[alphabetic,initials]{amsrefs}%this kills the up-arrows in the bibliography
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{hyperref} %prob
%\usepackage{showlabels}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\input xy%
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[pdftex]{pict2e}
\usepackage[aligntableaux=center]{ytableau}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}\frametitle{Example}


\begin{equation*}
%\resizebox{\displaywidth}{!}{%
\xymatrix@C=0.05pc@R=1pc{\emptyset\ar@{->}[r] &
\ydiagram{1}\ar@{->}[ddr]&
\ydiagram{1,1} \ar@{<-}[l] \ar@{->}[r]& \ydiagram{0+1,2}\ar@{->}[r] \ar@{->}[ddr]   &
\ydiagram{2,2} \ar@{->}[r]&\ydiagram{0+2,3} \ar@{->}[r] \ar@{->}[ddr]& \ydiagram{3,3}=\emptyset^{++}\ar@{->}[r]&
%\ydiagram{2,1+1,2+1,2+2,2+1}
\\ \\
%\ar@{-}[r] 
 \ydiagram{0+1,2}^{-}\ar@{->}[r] \ar@{->}[uur]&\ydiagram{2,2}^{-}\ar@{->}[r]&
\ydiagram{2}\ar@{<-}[l] \ar@{->}[r] \ar@{->}[uur]&\ydiagram{3}\ar@{->}[r]&
\ydiagram{0+1,3}\ar@{->}[r] \ar@{->}[uur]&\ydiagram{1,1}^+\ar@{->}[r]& \ydiagram{0+1,2}^+\ar@{->}[r]\ar@{->}[uur]&\\
0&1&2&3&4&5&6}
\end{equation*}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please include a screenshot? Thank you

Comment: You really, really, really want to clean up your preamble. Some of these packages do really nasty things to beamer's frame geometry.

Comment: In particular, please get rid of both instances of `\usepackage{fullpage}`.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a smaller font to make your diagram fit:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage[aligntableaux=center]{ytableau}

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Example}

\tiny
\begin{equation*}
\xymatrix@C=0.05pc@R=1pc{\emptyset\ar@{->}[r] &
\ydiagram{1}\ar@{->}[ddr]&
\ydiagram{1,1} \ar@{<-}[l] \ar@{->}[r]& \ydiagram{0+1,2}\ar@{->}[r] \ar@{->}[ddr]   &
\ydiagram{2,2} \ar@{->}[r]&\ydiagram{0+2,3} \ar@{->}[r] \ar@{->}[ddr]& \ydiagram{3,3}=\emptyset^{++}\ar@{->}[r]&
%\ydiagram{2,1+1,2+1,2+2,2+1}
\\ \\
%\ar@{-}[r] 
 \ydiagram{0+1,2}^{-}\ar@{->}[r] \ar@{->}[uur]&\ydiagram{2,2}^{-}\ar@{->}[r]&
\ydiagram{2}\ar@{<-}[l] \ar@{->}[r] \ar@{->}[uur]&\ydiagram{3}\ar@{->}[r]&
\ydiagram{0+1,3}\ar@{->}[r] \ar@{->}[uur]&\ydiagram{1,1}^+\ar@{->}[r]& \ydiagram{0+1,2}^+\ar@{->}[r]\ar@{->}[uur]&\\
0&1&2&3&4&5&6}
\end{equation*}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]